# pandas read from excel with multilevel columnnames and concat

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel with the following format

```
Product      Product_type    
ID           ColumnA        ColumnB        Start Date
10              12              14         01/01/2020
```

I need to be able to read the excel into a pandas dataframe and concat the multilevel columns so the output is

```
Product_ID     Product_type_ColumnA        ColumnB        Start Date
10              12                            14          01/01/2020
```

in some excel the top level columns could be one or more. It only needs to concat with the column name directly below it.

for example input

```
Product          
ID           ColumnA        ColumnB        Start Date
10
```

and required output

```
Product_ID      ColumnA        ColumnB        Start Date
10              12              14         01/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't very elegant but you could just import it as normal, then append the first row to the column names, then delete the first row:

```
# Import df (this would be from excel for you)
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns = ['ID', '', ''])

# Pick off first row and make into a list
col_names = df.values.tolist()[0]

# Put together the new column names
new_cols = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    new_cols.append(str(df.columns[i]) + '_' + str(col_names[i]))

# Replace the column names
df.columns = new_cols

# Remove the first row of the df
df = df[1:]
```